# Python Coding Need Assistance

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am having trouble with my code, I don't know what I can do. My code has a variable "bheight" and it splits into parts automatically(which I have coded and is good) but I want it so whenever it goes through the "def Building():" code it adds 1 onto bheight[0] so when it loops through next time it'll be bheight[1].

```
import turtle
turtle.bgcolor("orange")

blist = input('Please enter builidng heights e.g. "50 30 60"')
leo = turtle.Turtle()
bsplit = blist.split()
bheight = list(map(int, bsplit))
size = len(bsplit)

def Water():
    leo.penup()
    leo.goto(-200,0)
    leo.fillcolor('midnightblue')              
    leo.begin_fill()
    for a in range (1,3):
        leo.forward(400)
        leo.right(90)
        leo.forward(150)
        leo.right(90)
    leo.end_fill()
    leo.pendown()

def Building():
    for x in range (0,int(size)):
        leo.fillcolor('darkslategrey')
        leo.begin_fill()
        leo.left(90)
        leo.forward(bheight[-1+1])
        leo.right(90)
        leo.forward(20)
        leo.right(90)
        leo.forward(bheight[-1+1])
        leo.left(90)
        leo.end_fill()



def Reset():
    leo.towards(leo)  

Water()
Building()
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @maverick's index fix but don't see any need for the index in the first place.  Instead of:

```
for x in range (0,int(size)):
    ...
    leo.forward(bheight[x])
```

which really should be:

```
for x in range(size):
    ...
    leo.forward(bheight[x])
```

why not simply do:

```
for height in bheight:
        ...
        leo.forward(height)
```

The reworked code with this and various other style fixes:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def Water():
    leo.penup()
    leo.setx(-200)
    leo.fillcolor('midnightblue')

    leo.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        leo.forward(400)
        leo.right(90)
        leo.forward(150)
        leo.right(90)

    leo.end_fill()

    leo.pendown()

def Building():
    leo.fillcolor('darkslategrey')

    for height in bheight:
        leo.begin_fill()
        leo.left(90)
        leo.forward(height)
        leo.right(90)
        leo.forward(20)
        leo.right(90)
        leo.forward(height)
        leo.left(90)
        leo.end_fill()

blist = input('Please enter building heights e.g. "50 30 60": ')
bsplit = blist.split()
bheight = list(map(int, bsplit))

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("orange")

leo = Turtle()

Water()
Building()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the def building code:-

```
def Building():
    for x in range (0,int(size)):
        leo.fillcolor('darkslategrey')
        leo.begin_fill()
        leo.left(90)
        leo.forward(bheight[x])
        leo.right(90)
        leo.forward(20)
        leo.right(90)
        leo.forward(bheight[x])
        leo.left(90)
        leo.end_fill()
```

What was happening in your code was that everytime your where doing -1+1 which will get value at 0th index.Instead just add 'x'.